# Event Reciever for item added is fired multiple times

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

This is the code of my event reciever:

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {            
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://bp1amsapt283:2459/sites/TestSite");
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList list = web.Lists["CollegeList"];

            try
            {                   
                    SPList list1 = web.Lists["DestinationList"];
                    SPListItem item1 = list1.Items.Add();
                    if (list.ItemCount > 0)
                    {
                        SPListItem item = list.Items[list.ItemCount - 1];

                        item1["Title"] = item["Title"];
                        item1["First Name"] = item["First Name"];
                        item1["Middle Name"] = item["Middle Name"];
                        item1["Last Name"] = item["Last Name"];
                        item1["Date Of Birth"] = item["Date Of Birth"];

                        var add = item["Address"];
                        if (add.ToString().Contains("<"))
                        {
                            //string add1;
                            string[] add1 = add.ToString().Split('>');
                            string[] word = add1[1].Split('<');
                            item["Address"] = word[0];
                        }

                        item1["Address"] = item["Address"];
                        item1["Gender"] = item["Gender"];
                        item1["Courses"] = item["Courses"];
                        item1["Branch"] = item["Branch"];
                        item1["Approver"] = item["Approver"];
                        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

                        item1.Update();
                        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item1["Title"] = properties.AfterProperties["Title"];
                        item1["First Name"] = properties.AfterProperties["First Name"];
                        item1["Middle Name"] = properties.AfterProperties["Middle Name"];
                        item1["Last Name"] = properties.AfterProperties["Last Name"];
                        item1["Date Of Birth"] = properties.AfterProperties["Date Of Birth"];
                        item1["Address"] = properties.AfterProperties["Address"];
                        item1["Gender"] = properties.AfterProperties["Gender"];
                        item1["Courses"] = properties.AfterProperties["Courses"];
                        item1["Branch"] = properties.AfterProperties["Branch"];
                        item1["Approver"] = properties.AfterProperties["Approver"];
                    }
                }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Before the event is called, I have a visual webpart through which I am inserting the item into a list, and this event reciever is called upon that list to add an item into another list. The item is getting added but its added twice for a single item.Also, for each item, it first shows the previosuly added item and then displays the current item twice.Can anyone help me getting it resolved.

This is the code for my visual web part class file::

```
public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
{
    private static int iD = 0;
    private int myId = 0;

    public VisualWebPart1UserControl()
    {
        iD++;
        this.myId = iD;
    }


   public  int idcount()
   {
       return myId;
   }

    SPUser name;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
                SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                SPList list = web.Lists["CollegeList"];
                SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
                itemToAdd["Title"] = idcount();
                itemToAdd["First Name"] = TextBox3.Text;
                if (TextBox7.Text != "Enter Middlename Here")
                    itemToAdd["Middle Name"] = TextBox7.Text;
                itemToAdd["Last Name"] = TextBox8.Text;
                itemToAdd["Date Of Birth"] = TextBox9.Text;
                itemToAdd["Address"] = TextBox10.Text.ToString();
               // Console.WriteLine(itemToAdd["Address"]);
                itemToAdd["Gender"] = RadioButtonList2.Text;
                itemToAdd["Courses"] = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
                itemToAdd["Branch"] = DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
                itemToAdd["Approver"] = name;

                itemToAdd.Update();
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Success", "javascript:alert('form saved successfully.');", true);

                ClearTextBoxes(this);           
    }

    private void ClearTextBoxes(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).Text = "";
            }

            DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "BTech";
            DropDownList4.SelectedValue = "Mechanical";

            if (c is RadioButton)
            {
                ((RadioButton)c).Checked = false;
            }

            if(c is PeopleEditor)
            {
                ((PeopleEditor)c).Entities.Clear();
                ((PeopleEditor)c).ResolvedEntities.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> content = new List<string>();

        if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "BSc")
        {
            content.Add("Mathematics");
            content.Add("Biology");
            content.Add("Chemistry");

        }
        else if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "BTech")
        {
            content.Add("Mechanical");
            content.Add("Computer Science");
            content.Add("Electronics");
        }

        DropDownList4.DataSource = content;
        DropDownList4.DataBind();
        content.Clear();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);

        SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb();
        SPList list1 = oSPWeb.Lists["PeoplePicker"];

        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        int iPeople = PeopleEditor1.ResolvedEntities.Count;

        SPListItem itemToAdd1 = list1.Items.Add();


        for (int i = 0; i < iPeople; i++)
        {
            PickerEntity peEntity = PeopleEditor1.ResolvedEntities[i] as PickerEntity;

            SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(peEntity.Key);

            itemToAdd1["Approver"] = user;
            name = user;
            itemToAdd1.Update();
        }
    }

    protected void Unnamed4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.close();", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this event receiver attached to `CollegeList`?

Comment: Also, in your `else` block you set several properties on `item1`, but you never call `item1.Update()` in that block so these properties are never saved. Is this intentional? I presume the second `this.EventFiringEnabled = false;` call should be `this.EventFiringEnabled = true;` too?

Comment: yes, this event reciever is attached to "CollegeList".. I have  changed this.EventFiringEnbaled = true; and will item1.update() but its still not working

Comment: Why do you have `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }`?

Comment: You do know that `ItemAdded` isn't an event or even an event handler?

Comment: Try catch was added during debugging the code. and ItemAdded is an event which would be fired when an item would be added to corresponding list.!!

Comment: @Enigmativity Event handlers in SharePoint aren't bound in the same way as regular C# event handlers - the SharePoint framework handles the binding and calling of them. In reality they're just a class that inherits from `SPEventReceiverBase`.

Comment: @DeepanshiBansal When your event handler code is called, is `properties.ListItemId` the same both times it is called?

Comment: yes, it remains same.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything in the code that could cause this. Do you have access to the PowerShell management console? Follow the steps in [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/62060/7930) to see if it's listed twice.

Comment: @DeepanshiBansal - Then take out the `try`/`catch` as it'll cause more bugs than it removes.

Comment: @Mourndark - It's still not, in a C# strictly speaking manner, an event handler. It might be part of an eventing model, but it's just a overridden method.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the [Microsoft guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.aspx) for creating event receivers, particularly about creating and more importantly, disposing of, `SPSite` objects.